# What is the right implementation of the Dependency Inversion Principle in C#?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm building a password generator. I'm trying to apply the Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP) but so far my solution still seems to be coupled with concrete data.

How do I decouple the PasswordGenerator? So I don't have to pass to it

```
new PasswordRequirementsRepository(new PasswordRequirements{[properties assigned here]})
```

and I can inject an interface instead which will be used by IoC Container?
How can I pass in the data assigned to `PasswordRequirements` properties to the `PasswordGenerator` without creating an instance of `PasswordRequirementsRepository`?

I'm struggling when passing different sets of password requirements because in PasswordGenerator I have to pass a concrete instance of PasswordRequirementsRepository instead of interface. I guess what I'm trying to achieve is to decouple PasswordGenerator from the concrete set of password requirements.

**IPasswordRequirementsRepository.cs**

```
public interface IPasswordRequirementsRepository
{
    PasswordRequirements GetPasswordRequirements();
}
```

**PasswordRequirementsRepository.cs**

```
public class PasswordRequirementsRepository : IPasswordRequirementsRepository
{
    private readonly PasswordRequirements _requirements;

    public PasswordRequirementsRepository(PasswordRequirements requirements)
    {
        _requirements = requirements;
    }

    public PasswordRequirements GetPasswordRequirements()
    {
        return _requirements;
    }
}
```

**IPasswordGenerator.cs**

```
public interface IPasswordGenerator
{
    string GeneratePassword();
}
```

**PasswordGenerator.cs**

```
public class PasswordGenerator : IPasswordGenerator
{

    private readonly IPasswordRequirementsRepository _repository;

    public PasswordGenerator(IPasswordRequirementsRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public string GeneratePassword()
    {

      PasswordRequirements requirements = _repository.GetPasswordRequirements();

      [password generation logic here]

    }
}
```

**PasswordRequirements.cs**

```
public class PasswordRequirements
{
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public int NoUpper { get; set; }
    public int NoLower { get; set; }
    public int NoNumeric { get; set; }
    public int NoSpecial { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My question to you @xrsnik is: Why do you want to implement the Dependency inversion principle as it seems to me from what I have read that you are building a small solution and that what you are doing is over-engineering.
If that is the case, you should put in mind that simplicity is the ultimate sophistication.

Comment: @ Mohamed Kamel Bouzekria it's a learning project. it is definitely over engineering :)

Comment: Ok then :) This article should be of a great help then :
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1135745/Dependency-Inversion-Principle-DIP-2

Comment: I have trouble finding the actual question/problem here. The actual data should normally come from a database or a configuration file. For a detailed answer you need to specify the actual DI library etc.

Comment: @Henk Holterman Well I'm struggling when passing different sets of password requirements because in PasswordGenerator I have to pass a concrete instance of PasswordRequirementsRepository instead of interface. I guess what I'm trying to achieve is to decouple PasswordGenerator from the concrete set of password requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I decouple the PasswordGenerator? So I don't have to pass to it  and I can inject an interface instead which will be used by IoC Container?

1st - Derive an interface:

```
public class IPasswordRequirements
{
  int MaxLength { get; }
  int NoUpper { get; }
  int NoLower { get; }
  int NoNumeric { get; }
  int NoSpecial { get; }
}
```

2nd - Inherit from interface:

```
public class PasswordRequirements : IPasswordRequirements
{
  public int MaxLength { get; set; }
  public int NoUpper { get; set; }
  public int NoLower { get; set; }
  public int NoNumeric { get; set; }
  public int NoSpecial { get; set; }
}
```

3rd - Update constructor:

```
public class PasswordGenerator : IPasswordGenerator
{
  public PasswordGenerator(IPasswordRequirements passwordRequirements)
  {
  }
```

That's it.

*Don't use a repository here*

My fear is that your understanding of a repository and DI infer some time of requirement to always be used together.  What I believe your lacking is the code that instantiates dependencies.  While a repository may at it's core provide that as a bases of it's pattern, it isn't the correct choice here, because of two reasons; first you aren't storing the items in the repository (that is there is no tier virtual or physical abstraction to wrap the repository around) and secondly you aren't providing generic access to a wide variety of types, just a single one.

At it's core the only thing a repository needs to be useful is a *configuration/object* to pass objects.. to some other tier (SQL, File system, Web API).  A repository is not required in all instances to know anything about how objects are created.

*Choose a framework that fits your need*

Instead, what you need is a framework built at it's core around DI; object creation and disposal, and having an interface/configuration in which to configure the framework so it can be aware of dependencies to assist in the creation of dependent objects.  There are three that come to mind [AutoFac](https://autofac.org/), [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/wiki.html) and [Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity).  In each of these case, you are in some way, required to configure each type and use it's pattern to create objects.  In many cases these Frameworks can even be full featured replacements with other Microsoft Frameworks (MVC for example, has it's own way to instantiate objects, but can be replace with other DI Frameworks).  In no way are these frameworks required to know configuration on how to pass these objects to other tiers.  It may do so simply by configuration as a by-product, but at it's core that's not what is configured.

For example with Autofac, first you create builder which is basically a fancy way to create a configuration:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder()
```

Then you register your types:

```
builder.RegisterType<PasswordRequirements>.As<IPasswordRequirements>();
```

Create a *Container* which manages objects: from their instantiation to their configuration.

```
var container = builder.Build();
```

Create a scope which defines the duration of an objects lifetime.

```
using (var scope = new BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  // all objects created by scope which be disposed when the scope is diposed.

  var passwordRequirements = scope.Resolve<IPasswordRequirements>();
}
```

By default `passwordRequirements` will be a `new PasswordRequirements()`.  From there you simply build out your necessary dependency requirements and let the framework handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution!

Comment: You may want to make the base class methods either virtual or abstract

Answer (score 2):

> Crux of the issue related to Dependency Inversion

On creating the instance of the `PasswordGenerator`. which inject, `IPasswordRequirementsRepository`, in current design there's a limitation of passing the concrete instance of `PasswordRequirements`, which shall be avoided for true Dependency inversion design.

---

**Following are the possible solutions:**

1. Create an interface or preferably an abstract class for the `PasswordRequirements`, which can be overridden and can be injected on the need basis, which will be automatically injected when `IPasswordRequirementsRepository` is injected in the `PasswordGenerator`

Let's consider the abstract class:

```
public abstract class BasePasswordRequirements
{
    public abstract int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public abstract int NoUpper { get; set; }
    public abstract int NoLower { get; set; }
    public abstract int NoNumeric { get; set; }
    public abstract int NoSpecial { get; set; }
}

public class PasswordRequirements : BasePasswordRequirements
{
    public override int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public override int NoUpper { get; set; }
    public override int NoLower { get; set; }
    public override int NoNumeric { get; set; }
    public override int NoSpecial { get; set; }
}
```

Using [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/wiki.html) DI container Binding would be as follows, along with named binding:

```
 Kernel.Bind<IPasswordRequirementsRepository>().To<PasswordRequirementsRepository>()
 Kernel.Bind<BasePasswordRequirements>().To<PasswordRequirements>()
```

**PasswordRequirementsRepository** will be as follows:

```
public class PasswordRequirementsRepository : IPasswordRequirementsRepository
{
    private readonly BasePasswordRequirements Requirements{get;}

    public PasswordRequirementsRepository(BasePasswordRequirements requirements)
    {
        Requirements = requirements;
    }

    public BasePasswordRequirements GetPasswordRequirements()
    {
        return Requirements;
    }
}
```

2. Another option would be constructor Injection, in that case `PasswordRequirements`, may not need a Base class or interface, in that case binding would be like:

   ```
   Kernel.Bind<IPasswordRequirementsRepository>().To<PasswordRequirementsRepository>()
                        .WithConstructorArgument("requirements", new 
   PasswordRequirements { .... });
   ```

This would call the correct constructor, with relevant values filled in

You may also consider combination of both approached 1 and 2 , where you create a base class / interface for `PasswordRequirements` and also constructor injection.

---

For various versions of `PasswordRequirements`, that you may want to inject consider named binding, following shall be example, instead of:

```
 public class PasswordRequirementsRepository : IPasswordRequirementsRepository
    {
        private readonly Func<string,BasePasswordRequirements> RequirementsFunc{get;}

        public PasswordRequirementsRepository(Func<string,BasePasswordRequirements> requirementsFunc)
        {
            RequirementsFunc = requirementsFunc;
        }

        public BasePasswordRequirements GetPasswordRequirements(string name="Version1")
        {
            return requirementsFunc(name);
        }
    }
```

**Ninject Binding would be as follows**

```
    Kernel.Bind<Func<string,BasePasswordRequirements>>()
            .ToMethod(context => name => context.Kernel
                                             .Get<BasePasswordRequirements>(name); 
                           );


    Bind<BasePasswordRequirements>().To<PasswordRequirements>().Named("Version1"); 
    Bind<BasePasswordRequirements>().To<AnotherPasswordRequirements>().Named("Version2");
```

Here the Name for Binding can be passed at the run-time to tweak object that will be injected and thus change the behavior by run-time, thus achieving dependency inversion by using a **DI framework** like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/wiki.html), which lot of flexible options

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use generics to abstract out the different types of password requirements you might use, and pass the options through the GeneratePassword method since that's really a parameter to how you generate the password. I.E.

```
interface IPasswordGenerator<TPasswordRequirements>
{
  string GeneratePassword(TPasswordRequirements reqs);
}

interface IPasswordRequirementRepository<TPasswordRequirements>
{
  TPasswordRequirements GetPasswordRequirements();
}
```

Implemented by

```
class DefaultPasswordReqs
{
  public int MaxLength { get; set; }
  // ...
}

class DefaultPasswordGenerator : IPasswordGenerator<DefaultPasswordReqs>
{
  public string GeneratePassword(DefaultPasswordReqs reqs)
  {
    // ... logic specific to DefaultPasswordReqs
  }
}

class InMemoryPasswordRequiremntsRepository<TPasswordRequirements> : 
  IPasswordRequirementRepository<TPasswordRequirements>
{
  private readonly TPasswordRequirements _reqs;

  public InMemoryPasswordRequiremntsRepository(TPasswordRequirements reqs)
  {
    _reqs = reqs;
  }

  public TPasswordRequirements GetPasswordRequirements()
  {
    return _reqs;
  }
}
```

And then in whatever code depends on the password generator, have it take a dependency which has the specifc type of password requirements it will use and read the requirements and use those requirements to generate the password.

```
var requirements = _passwordRequiremntsRepository.GetPasswordRequirements();
var password = _passwordGenerator.GeneratePassword(requirements);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code snippet in your question, the implementation of `PasswordGenerator` is decoupled from the implementation of the `IPasswordRequirementsRepository` as it is the interface that is given as constructor argument and not a specific implementation.

To decouple the `PasswordRequirementsRepository` from a specific implementation of the `PasswordRequirements` you can do one of two things.

1. Introduce an interface `IPasswordRequirements`.
2. Make `PasswordRequirements` abstract.

Either approach will decouple the implementation of `PasswordRequirementsRepository` from the implementation of `PasswordRequirements`.

## DI container

> How do I decouple the PasswordGenerator? So I don't have to pass to it
> `new PasswordRequirementsRepository(new PasswordRequirements{[properties assigned here]})`
> and I can inject an interface instead which will be used by IoC Container? How can I pass in the data assigned to PasswordRequirements properties to the PasswordGenerator without creating an instance of PasswordRequirementsRepository?

I believe that this part of the question builds on a misunderstanding of the role of the DI container. When building your container you will register all the Classes/Interfaces that is needed in your system. This could look something like the following:

```
Register<IPasswordRequirements>().To<PasswordRequirements>();
Register<IPasswordRequirementsRepository>().To<PasswordRequirementsRepository>();
Register<IPasswordGenerator>().To<PasswordGenerator>();
```

After registering everything you can ask the container to provide you with an instance of an interface. In your case, this would be an instance of `IPasswordGenerator`. The request typically looks a something like this:

```
var passwordGenerator = contain.Resolve<IPasswordGenerator>();
```

Normally you only request the topmost component of your program, as the DI container knows what is needed to instantiate every class the component depends on. You would not create a new instance of `PasswordGenerator` by manually resolving the dependencies and the inject these into the constructor. This approach counteracts the purpose of the DI container.